# ComboBoxTableCell, Callback

Tags: javafx, combobox, tablecell

I have a question that I can not solve in any way. I've read everything I've found on the web, and tried dozens of codes, but I still have no solution.

It is a JavaFX project that follows the MVC model. The fxml file is the following:

The main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        AnchorPane root = null;
        try {
            root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

The controller for the fxml file is:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Fila> taula;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Fila, String> c1;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Fila, ObservableList<String>> c2;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert taula != null : "fx:id=\"taula\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'sample.fxml'.";
        assert c1 != null : "fx:id=\"c1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'sample.fxml'.";
        assert c2 != null : "fx:id=\"c2\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'sample.fxml'.";

        ObservableList<Fila> dades = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Fila("First", FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3")),
                new Fila("Second", FXCollections.observableArrayList("4", "5", "6")),
                new Fila("Third", FXCollections.observableArrayList("7", "8", "9"))
        );

        c1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().c1Property());

        c2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().c2Property());



        taula.setItems(dades);

    }
}
```

And the bean class is:

```
public class Fila {

    private StringProperty c1;
    private ListProperty<String> c2;

    public Fila(String c1, ObservableList<String> c2) {
        this.c1 = new SimpleStringProperty(c1);
        this.c2 = new SimpleListProperty<>(c2);
    }

    public String getC1() {
        return c1.get();
    }

    public StringProperty c1Property() {
        return c1;
    }

    public void setC1(String c1) {
        this.c1.set(c1);
    }

    public ObservableList<String> getC2() {
        return c2.get();
    }

    public ListProperty<String> c2Property() {
        return c2;
    }

    public void setC2(ObservableList<String> c2) {
        this.c2.set(c2);
    }
}
```

What I do not get is that in the second column a `ComboBox` appears, with the values ​​that now appear as `List` ...

I think it could be achieved using the `setCellFactory` method together with a `Callback` for column where we want the `ComboBox`, but I am unable to get it ...

Sorry for my level of English; It's obvious that I'm using a translator ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
    c2.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Fila, ObservableList<String>>() {

        private final ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();

        {
            combo.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                // in real life, update model appropriately here...
                System.out.println("Selected "+newValue+" for "+getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).getC1());
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(ObservableList<String> items, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(items, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                combo.setItems(items);
                // in real life, do combo.setValue(...) with some value from model
                setGraphic(combo);
            }
        }
    });
```

Your model doesn't really supply enough information for a combo box, as it doesn't have any property representing which item in the combo box is selected. Presumably you just didn't add this in the example you posted; the listener on the combo box's `valueProperty()` should update this appropriately, and the `updateItem()` method should set the value of the combo box depending on the appropriate data.

Comment: Thank you very much, James_D. It's a simple, elegant solution, and it works perfectly.